# Can't ride or feed horses in my survival world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Let me start off by saying that I don't know how to reproduce this problem, it affects all horses in my survival world. I generally keep my horses leashed to a fence post and then suddenly one day my skeleton horse was wandering around my village. I didn't untie the leash so I am confused as to how this happened. Since then I've been unable to ride any of the horses in my survival world. It is probably worth noting that the feed and ride buttons still appear but when I tap them they do nothing. The horse I found of the leash was a skeleton horse with a saddle on him and I'm reluctant to kill him as I heard that horses don't drop saddles they're wearing. I'm also on MCPE 0.15.0, Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was a leash error. I put another leash on the horse and unleashed it and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. I have to wait 20 hours til I can tick it...